# ¿Por qué no siempre funciona el método sort en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, matrices, random

Quiero ordenar en *JavaScript* un array en forma de tabla generada aleatoriamente con números, de mayor a menor, en este caso, la columna 1. Hay veces que la ordena, pero otras veces no.

El array de ejemplo sería este:

> ```
> var array=[[3],[0,713,751,828,833,905],[0,300],[1,654,710]]
> ```

```
Columna| 0 |1 esta|  2 |  3  |  4   |  5  |
-------+---|-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
       | 3 |     |     |     |      |     |
       | 0 | 713 | 751 | 828 | 833  | 905 |
       | 0 | 300 |     |     |      |     |
       | 1 | 654 | 710 |     |      |     |
-------+---+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

La tabla ordenada debería quedar así:

```
Columna| 0 |1 esta|  2 |  3  |  4   |  5  |
-------+---|-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
       | 0 | 713 | 751 | 828 | 833  | 905 |
       | 1 | 654 | 710 |     |      |     |
       | 0 | 300 |     |     |      |     |
       | 3 |     |     |     |      |     |
-------+---+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

La cuestión es que al aplicar el método `sort` para ordenar la columna 1, en vez de quedar como quiero, queda así.

```
Columna| 0 |1 esta|  2 |  3  |  4   |  5  |
-------+---|-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
       | 3 |     |     |     |      |     |
       | 0 | 713 | 751 | 828 | 833  | 905 |
       | 1 | 654 | 710 |     |      |     |
       | 0 | 300 |     |     |      |     |
-------+---+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

Código del array de ejemplo:

```js
var array=[[3],[0,713,751,828,833,905],[0,300],[1,654,710]]
document.write(JSON.stringify(array.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a[1]>b[1]){return -1}
  if(a[1]<b[1]){return 1}
  return 0
})))
```

Código de mi programa:

```js
function mostrar_array(array)
{
  var devuelve=""
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  {
    if(array[i]!=undefined)
    {
      devuelve+="<div>"+array[i]+"</div>"
    }
  }
  return devuelve
}
function generar()
{
  var array=[]
  for(var i=0;i<1000;i++)
  {
    var aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
    if(aleatorio==1)
    {
      aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
      if(array[aleatorio]==undefined)
      {
        array[aleatorio]=[
          aleatorio=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
        ]
      }
      else
      {
        array[aleatorio].push(i)
      }
    }
  }
  texto.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(array)
  texto.innerHTML+="<div>Array normal.</div>"
  texto.innerHTML+=mostrar_array(array)
  texto.innerHTML+="<div>Array ordenado.</div>"
  texto.innerHTML+=mostrar_array(array.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a[1]>b[1]){return -1}
    if(a[1]<b[1]){return 1}
    return 0
  }))
}
```

```html
<button onclick=generar()>Generar y ordenar</button> Ordenando la columna 1.
<p id=texto>Clickear el botón para generar.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas manejando matrices irregulares y el que la "columna" utilizada para ordenar no existe en todos los renglones.

Una manera de resolver esto es "forzar" a que la columna a usar para ordenar simpre tenga un elemento. Si este elemento va a ser vacío usar `null` o `undefined`.

A continuación pongo el primer stack snippet al que he agregado `null` como segundo elemento del primer "renglón"

```js
var array=[[3,null],[0,713,751,828,833,905],[0,300],[1,654,710]]
document.write(JSON.stringify(array.sort(function(a,b){
  if(a[1]>b[1]){return -1}
  if(a[1]<b[1]){return 1}
  return 0
})))
```

Nota: El usar términos como renglón y columnas es una convención. Hablando en términos de JavaScript puro, se trata de una matriz cuyos elementos son otras matrices.